# Chaining declarations of property / field in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

For example, in java, we can do something like:

`int first = 1, second = 2, third = 3;`

How to do such thing in Kotlin **aside** from declaring one-by-one like:

```
var first: Int = 1
var second: Int = 2
var third: Int = 3
```

**Maybe** something like this (I know below code **doesn't work** in kotlin, just to make a visualization)

`var first = 1, second = 2, third = 3: Int //Error`

---

**ADDITIONAL NOTES (What I already know)**

I definitely didn't mean this:

`var first: Integer = 1; var second: Integer = 2; var third: Integer = 3`

Neither this:

`var first = 1; var second = 2; var third = 3`

Comment: TL;DR: this feature is not present in Kotlin.

Comment: @zsmb13 whoop, missed that search result. :( Flagged as duplicate. Thanks

Comment: You could use destructuring though. 2 arguments: `val (first, second) = 1 to 2`. 3 arguments: `val (first, second, third) = Triple(1,2,3)`. For more, you need a data class. I wouldn't really recommend doing it unless you have the object to destructure from before though. You shouldn't create an object just to destructure it.